# perl: Running unix processes and monitoring them using perl

Tags: perl, process

I have 24 tasks (unix commands) in the list (file). they need to be executed by 5 at the given time. When a task completes the script should execute a next one until all 24 tasks are executed/competed. Meanwhile in foreground I have a while loop with "ps" command to monitor the activity. Any ideas?

Comment: The feature you are looking for is process throttling. Check out a module like [`Parallel::ForkManager`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager) or [`Forks::Super`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Forks::Super).

Comment: GNU Parallel is a Perl program that happens to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

```
use Parallel::ForkManager qw( );

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(5);
for my $task (@tasks) {
   $pm->start() and next;
   my $exit_code = 0;
   if (!eval {
      ...
      return 1;  # No exception
   }) {
      $exit_code = $! || $? >> 8 || 255;
      warn($@);
   }

   $pm->finish($exit_code);
}

$pm->wait_all_children();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get info from your process monitoring with [Proc::ProcessTable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Proc::ProcessTable)

This is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Proc::ProcessTable;

$ref = new Proc::ProcessTable;

foreach $proc (@{$ref->table}) {
  if(@ARGV) {
    next unless grep {$_ == $proc->{pid}} @ARGV;
  }

  print "--------------------------------\n";
  foreach $field ($ref->fields){
    print $field, ":  ", $proc->{$field}, "\n";
  }
}
```

If you´re using Windows, maybe you can use Win32::Process* modules. But I never used!